# Count frequency of multiple words

Tags: pandas, count, frequency

[image: syntax error]
[image: snippet of the output]

I used this code

```
unclassified_df['COUNT'] = unclassified_df.tweet.str.count('mulcair')
```

to count the number of times mulcair appeared in each row in my pandas dataframe. I am trying to repeat the same but for a set of words such as

```
Liberal = ['lpc','ptlib','justin','trudeau','realchange','liberal', 'liberals', "liberal2015",'lib2015','justin2015', 'trudeau2015', 'lpc2015']
```

I saw somewhere that I could use `collection.Counter(data)` and its `.most_common(k)` method for such, please can anyone help me out.

Comment: Do you have to use pandas specifically ?

Comment: Yeah I would like to

Comment: so now you want to find the number of times 'mulcair' is in the liberal list ?

Comment: No, I need python to check each row in the dataframe and each row that contains any word in the liberal list, it will return a frequency showing the total number of words from the liberal list contained in that row.

Comment: How does your DataFrame look? Can you add a snippet ?

Comment: I have included it in the original post, thank you

Comment: i have provided a solution for you.

Comment: it looks like i have to revise my solution. Give me a sec

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

#check frequency for the following for each row, but no repetition for row  
Liberal =  ['lpc','justin','trudeau','realchange','liberal', 'liberals', "liberal2015",       'lib2015','justin2015', 'trudeau2015', 'lpc2015']

#sample data
data = {'tweet': ['lpc living dream camerama', "jsutingnasndsa dnsadnsadnsa dsalpcdnsa",      "but", 'mulcair suggests thereslcp bad lpc blood']}

# the data frame with one coloumn tweet
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['tweet'])

#no duplicates per row
print [(df.tweet.str.contains(word).sum(),word) for word in Liberal]

#captures all duplicates located in  each row
print pd.Series({w: df.tweet.str.count(w).sum() for w in Liberal})
```

[image: Code Execution]

**References:** 
[Contains & match](https://davidhamann.de/2017/06/26/pandas-select-elements-by-string/)

Comment: thank you but it says  invalid syntax for word in Liberal

Comment: make sure you copy  the whole code, don't mix any of the enclosed statements

Comment: You have an extra colon in the list comprehension, Please check and try to copy the snippet of code as I have posted here@SamuelAbiola

Comment: oh thanks it worked but I wanted it to return for every row the total number of words from the list in liberal within the row

Comment: thanks but it sums the total number of words contained in the entire data instead of taking it row by row

Comment: This is what it gives me now ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, it seems that you lack some understanding here about the panda libraries. I have never used panda, and I was able to generate that solution quite fast given that I was not 100%. If you want row by row why use pandas? Pandas aim to eliminate the constraints and bottlenecks that list have, which in my opinion are dismissible.

Comment: Supply a snippet of where that error is happening ?

Comment: sighs it still returns the total for the entire data in the dataframe instead of by row

Comment: If the solution suits you check the answer on the left.